# I want to print the arrayList in reverse by passing the arraylist to a new stack in java

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections, stack

This assignment ask to implement `printWordRun` so that it prints whatever word run it can find starting from the beginning of the input list `words`. The word run should be printed in reverse order, with each word on a separate line. PrintWordRun is a method which takes a parameter called `words` which is an `ArrayList<String>`. The word run is a series of words in the input list, where each word is longer in length than the previous. The word run ends once we either encounter the end of the list, or we encounter a word whose length is equal to or shorter than the previous word.

The array is:

I
am
cat
with
happy
dog
sitting

the result should be:

happy
with 
cat
am
I

To get full credit for this assignment, I have to use a stack to print it as I have done, but I cannot get the word "happy" into the stack. My output is:

I
am
cat
with

```
public class Program {
    private void printWordRun(ArrayList<String> words) {

        // Here is the code I Wrote. 
        Stack<String> wordRun = new Stack<>();

        for(int i = 1; i < words.size(); i++) {
            String str1 = words.get(i-1);
            String str2 = words.get(i);
            if(str2.length() < str1.length()) {
                break;
            }
            if(str1.length() < str2.length()){
                wordRun.push(str1);

            }


            System.out.println(wordRun);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.testPrintWordRun();
    }

    private void testPrintWordRun() {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("I");
        words.add("am");
        words.add("cat");
        words.add("with");
        words.add("happy");
        words.add("dog");
        words.add("sitting");

        System.out.println("Testing printWordRun...");
        printWordRun(words);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh i forgot to add the code. just edited the original post

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to construct the `printWordRun` function:

```java
Stack<String> wordRun = new Stack<>();
int maxLength = 0;

for(String s : words) {

    if(s.length() > maxLength ) {
        maxLength = s.length();
        wordRun.add(s);
    } else
        break;
}

while(!wordRun.isEmpty())
    System.out.println(wordRun.pop());
```

Just store a value of the current, maximum length and use this to compare your current string.

Output:

```
Testing printWordRun...
happy
with
cat
am
I
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding the word to the stack with `add(int index, E element)` to insert the last item as first, and break the loop if the condition doesn't match afterwards.

```
private void printWordRun(ArrayList<String> words) {

    // Here is the code I Wrote.
    Stack<String> wordRun = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 1; i < words.size(); i++) {
        String str1 = words.get(i);
        String str2 = words.get(i - 1);
        wordRun.add(0, str2);
        if(str2.length() >= str1.length()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(wordRun); // [happy, with, cat, am, I]
}
```

Comment: ok so this code do not print the word happy. the rest populate in the output

Comment: @Bobby No, the `I` is not missing. Did you edit it? make sure the print is after the `for` loop.

Comment: and i also switched the '>' to '<'. with '>' nothing prints. so i switched it and got : with, cat, am, i

Comment: @Bobby I just tested this code again, it prints `[happy, with, cat, am, I]`. You don't need to change anything, just copy past it. Also make sure you run the correct file.

Comment: thats strange. thank you. so simple but i struggled with it.

Comment: is there a way to print each index on a separate line? i have to do that.

Comment: see my answer: `while(!wordRun.isEmpty()) System.out.println(wordRun.pop());`

Comment: @Bobby Just print the items in `wordRun` with a loop `for (String word: wordRun) { System.out.println(word); }`

Comment: @Sebphil ok. i did it but it dont print it in reverse. it do print on a separate line.

Comment: Yes because this answer does not use the Stack class as it is intended to be used. You should add items to the stack using the `push` or `add` methods (without an index). The stack handles everything for you. You will also get wrong results if the length of both strings that are compared are equal. Currently, this answer uses the stack as if it would be a list.

Comment: @sebphil thx your code works exactly how the output should be... thanks